# How to find big-O for these tricky for-loops?

Tags: loops, for-loop, runtime, big-o, nested-loops

I wanted to confirm if I got the correct big-O for a few snippets of code involving for-loops.

```
for ( int a = 0; a < n; a ++)
    for ( int b = a; b < 16 ; b ++)
        sum += 1;
```

I think this one is O(16N) => O(N), but the fact that b starts at a rather than 0 in the second for-loop is throwing me off.

```
int b = 0;
for ( int a = 0; a < n ; a ++)
    sum += a * n;
    for ( ; b < n ; b ++)
        sum++;
```

I want to say O(N^2) since there are nested for-loops where both loops go to n. However, b in the second loop uses the initialization from the outer scope, and I'm not sure if that affects the runtime.

```
for (int a = 0; a < (n * n); a ++)
    sum++;
    if (a % 2 == 1)
        for (; a < (n * n * n); a ++)
            sum++;
```

I got that the first for-loop is O(N^2) and the one under the if-statement is O(N^3), but I don't know how to account for the if-statement.

Answer (score -2):

The first one is `O(n*min(n, 16))` because the 16-for-loop counts as `O(1)` assuming `n > 16`. if `n < 16` then it's `O(n^2)`.

The second one is `O(n)` because after the first iteration `b` is already `n`.

The third one is `O(n^3)` because after a maximum of 2 iterations you reach the if statement and then `a` is incremented until `n^3` which means that in the next outer for-loop iteration `a<n*n` is indeed true so it will exit out of the for loop entirely.

Hopefully this answers your questions, good luck!

Comment: The first answer should be O(n).

Comment: @MoB. So just to be sure, is my reasoning correct for that first one? Or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. It's easy to see that substituting 0 for *a* in the inner loop cannot decrease the time complexity. So the inner loop is O(1).

Comment: The rest of the answer by Herr Flick  is correct, btw.